# Open web page on click at a button in a JetBrains Space chat message using Kotlin SDK

Tags: kotlin, jetbrains-space

I have a simple chat bot that renders "on this day" facts based on Wikipedia.

As you can see, there's a button on my UI. I want that if the user taps on it, a new browser tab opens with given Wikipedia url.

Until now, I only see the possibility to send other messages using buttons and there action (`PostMessageAction`).

Do you have any tip on how to achieve my feature idea?

**Code**

```kotlin
      private fun makeMessage(container: OnThisDay): ChatMessage {
            return message {
...
                section {
                    text("On this day (${container.date}) happened:")

                    container.happenings.reversed().forEach {
                        text(
                            size = MessageTextSize.SMALL,
                            content = "${it.year}:\n${it.description}",
                        )

                        controls {
                            wikipediaButton(it.wikipediaUrl) <-- BUTTON
                        }

                        divider()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private fun MessageControlGroupBuilder.wikipediaButton(urlString: String) {
            val action = PostMessageAction("a", "b") <-- NO other action possible?
            button("Open Wikipedia", action, MessageButtonStyle.SECONDARY)
        }
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Space Chat bot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NavigateUrlAction` for this. Here's an example:

```kotlin
message {
    section {
        controls {
            button(
                text = "Open Wikipedia",
                style = MessageButtonStyle.PRIMARY,
                action = NavigateUrlAction(
                    url = "https://wikipedia.org",
                    withBackUrl = false,
                    openInNewTab = true
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have a documentation page where all of the action types, etc. are listed? I was not able to find it :(

Comment: You can use API Playground to create a sample API request. There you'll find all the possible parameter values, not only for button actions, but for any enumeration-like parameter of any API method.

You can find API Playground in `Extensions` top-level menu.